# Making simple timer using javascript but getting weird behavior

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm a beginner at Javascript. I'm trying to make a timer. It works good, but when comes to the  `Pause` and `Stop` buttons, they don't function well at all...

- For `Pause` button.. let's say timer is on `0:58` when `Pause` button is pressed, it stops at `0:58` but when i press it again to resume the
  countdown .. it just become `0:57` .. And stops afterwards, it
  doesn't continue till 0:00 !
- And for the `Stop` button.. When i simply press it, it gives this error
  :

  Uncaught ReferenceError: checkstate is not defined

Here's the whole code combined so you guys can test it and let me know if there's something else :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body, p, input, button {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            html , body {
                height : 100%;
            }

            #mainContent {
                width : 300px;  
                height : 200px;
                margin: 50px auto;
            }

            #seconds {
                padding : 10px;
                font-size : 15px;
                font-weight:bold;
            }

            button {
                padding : 10px;
            }

            #interfereButton {
                margin : 0 40px;
            }


            #timer {        
                width :  200px;
                height: 100px;
                margin-top: 20px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size : 60px;
                text-align : center;
            }           
        </style>
        <title>Timer</title>        
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="mainContent">
                <div id="userControl">
                    <input type="text" name="seconds" id="seconds"/>
                    <button id="start">Start</button>
                </div>
                <p id="timer">0:00</p>
                <div id="interfereButton">
                    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
                    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
                    var start = document.getElementById("start");
                    var startPoint = document.getElementById("seconds");
                    var userControl = document.getElementById("userControl");
                    var userInterfere = document.getElementById("interfereButton");
                    var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
                    var stop = document.getElementById("stop");

                    var timerHandle;
                    var tempValue;

                    function checkState(){
                        if (timer.innerHTML == "0:00"){
                            userControl.style.display = "block";
                            userInterfere.style.display = "none";
                            timer.style.color = "black";
                        } else {
                            userControl.style.display = "none";
                            userInterfere.style.display = "block";
                        }
                    }

                    function activate(x){
                        var min = x.split(":")[0];
                        var sec = x.split(":")[1];

                        if(min >= 0){
                            sec--;
                            if(sec < 0){
                                sec = 59;
                                min--;
                                if(min < 0) {
                                    sec = "00" ;
                                    min = 0 ;               
                                    clearInterval(timerHandle);
                                }           
                            } else if(sec < 10) {
                                sec = "0" + sec;
                                timer.style.color = "red";          
                            }
                            timer.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec ;
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(timerHandle);
                        }   

                        checkState();
                    }


                    start.onclick = function() {
                        if(!isNaN(startPoint.value)){
                            timer.innerHTML= startPoint.value + ":00" ;
                            userControl.style.display = "none";
                            userInterfere.style.display = "block";
                            timerHandle = setInterval("activate(timer.innerHTML)" , 1000);
                        } else {
                            alert("Sorry, only numerical values are allowed.");
                        }
                    }

                    pause.onclick = function() {
                        if(pause.innerHTML == "Pause"){
                            tempValue = timer.innerHTML;
                            clearInterval(timerHandle);
                            pause.innerHTML = "Resume";
                        } else if(pause.innerHTML == "Resume"){
                            timerHandle = setInterval("activate(tempValue)" , 1000);
                            pause.innerHTML = "Pause";
                        }
                    }

                    stop.onclick = function(){
                        clearInterval(timerHandle);
                        timer.innerHTML = "0:00";
                        checkstate();   
                    }

                    window.onload = function(){
                        userInterfere.style.display = "none";
                    }   
                </script>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but should he wrap the JS in a function to prevent global variables?

Comment: @ZachL.: You are correct. It is a much better policy to explicitly declare a variable to be global than to allow all your outer-scope variables to be global by default.

Comment: @ZachL. Can you tell me how to do that ? is it just wrapping the code with `function() { ... }` ?

Comment: See the example in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663540/7663882#7663882

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is when you attempt to resume, you're calling set interval passing `tempValue`.  `tempValue` is then not changed.  So every time your interval fires, it's passing the same value to it.  You can fix this by just eliminating `tempValue` and using `timer.innerHTML` the same way you do initially.

http://jsfiddle.net/WkuSG/

As for the stop button, check your method name, you've typoed, the S should be capitol.

---

Some other notes.  You really shouldn't use `setInterval` passing a string.  Internally that uses `eval` which is bad.  It is better to pass a function.  Something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    activate(timer.innerHTML);
}, 1000);
```

And finally, you can't really count on `setInterval` being accurate.  If this timer needs to be very accurate you will need to compare timestamps.  Since javascript is single-threaded, some other javascript could end up throwing off your time.

Comment: Oh, thanks that solved it. And thanks for the note. But i'm a beginner can you clarify the note about `setInterval` being not accurate ?

Comment: Re: accuracy of `setInterval`, see what John Resig has to say: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part of your question: in your `stop.onclick` you're calling checkstate() whereas the function is called checkState. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

First,

your call to `checkstate()` is wrong. It differs in case from the defined function, `checkState`.

B. I don't know what you're doing with the tempValue in the Pause/Result. Also there's no need to pass a value to your tick function (which you called "activate", but it's really a tick).  Inside the tick function, just get the content of the DIV.

working example:
http://jsbin.com/ohoqot

also, it's a good idea to wrap your functions in a scope:

```
(function(globalScope) {
    'use strict';

    var timer, start, startPoint, userControl, userInterfere, pause,
        stop, timerHandle, tempValue;

    function tick() { .... }

    ... other functions here ...

    window.onload = function(){
      setGlobals();
      setupBindings();
      userInterfere.style.display = "none";
    };

}(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It really helped.